# Can a relative adjective begin a conditional statement in Attic Greek?

Tags: greek, relative-pronouns, conditions

In my textbook, there's a chapter on conditional relative clauses, in which it explains how relative pronouns and adverbs, especially when they are indefinite, can form the protasis of a conditional statement.

For example,

> Whoever has a sword and shield should help protect the wall.

In the above example, "whoever" is an indefinite relative pronoun. The protasis consists of "whoever has a sword and shield"; the apodosis, of "should help protect the wall".

But what about relative adjectives? Can a relative adjective describing the subject (or object) of a clause also give that clause conditional force?

For example,

> Take whichever swords are at at hand; we shall need whichever arms you may find.

Are there conditions in the above example?

I ask because, as far as I know, what qualifies as a condition often requires certain particles or moods. It would thus affect the way I compose the above example in Greek.

I appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the construction is the same whether the relative is modifying a noun (relative adjective) or not (relative pronoun). The latter type is more frequent, but there are examples of the former, e.g. this from [Smyth](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Smyth+grammar+2565&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0007):

> ὥστ᾽ ἀποφύγοις ἂν ἥντιν᾽ ἂν βούλῃ δίκην
>    "so that you can get off in any suit you please” (Ar. Nub. 1151)